# Insert multiple entities at a time: Room

Tags: android, android-room

I have an entities called **BloodShareContact**. I want to store list of this entities at a time. But it stores only one entity though it has more than one.

```
@Dao
public interface BloodShareDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    List<Long> insertAllBloodShareContact(List<BloodShareContact> contactList);

}
```

Repository Looks like.

```
public class BloodShareRepository {

private BloodShareDatabase bloodDatabase;

public BloodShareRepository(Context context) {
    bloodDatabase = BloodShareDatabase.getDataBaseInstance(context);
}

public void insertContacts(List<BloodShareContact> contactArrayList) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            bloodDatabase.bloodShareDao().insertAllBloodShareContact(contactArrayList);

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

**BloodShareContact** Entity

```
@Entity
public class BloodShareContact {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int bid;

    private String blood_group;
    private String mobile;
    private String name;

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getBid() {
        return bid;
    }

    public void setBid(int bid) {
        this.bid = bid;
    }

    public void setBlood_group(String blood_group) {
        this.blood_group = blood_group;
    }

    public String getBlood_group() {
        return blood_group;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "BloodShareContact{" +
                        "mobile = '" + mobile + '\'' +
                        ",blood_group = '" + blood_group + '\'' +
                        "}";
    }
}
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the ids are unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try setting the primary key to auto generate.

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int bid
```

Then set all of the `bid` to 0. This will make sure all the primary keys are unique. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey.html#autoGenerate()

Comment: i am trying. wait please

Comment: seems problem is solved. I am leaving ofc. tomorrow will test finally and accept.